# Angularjs: ngRoute error injection with angular Material

Tags: angularjs

i am leaning `Angular.js` and i want to add `ngRoute` to start making applications with routes, so i have this problem, when i just add `ngRoute` to the module (this module also loads `ngMaterial`, `ngAnimate`, and `ngAria`), the browser throws me an error angular doesn't work anymore.

app.js

```
(function(angular)
{
    var app = angular.module('Organizer', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($mdThemingProvider, $httpProvider)
    {
        // Config theme
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
            .primaryPalette('blue-grey');

        // Config http post
        // Use x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

        /**
        * The workhorse; converts an object to x-www-form-urlencoded serialization.
        * @param {Object} obj
        * @return {String}
        */ 
        var param = function(obj) {
            var query = '', name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;

            for(name in obj) {
                value = obj[name];

                if(value instanceof Array) {
                    for(i=0; i<value.length; ++i) {
                        subValue = value[i];
                        fullSubName = name + '[' + i + ']';
                        innerObj = {};
                        innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                        query += param(innerObj) + '&';
                    }
                }
                else if(value instanceof Object) {
                    for(subName in value) {
                        subValue = value[subName];
                        fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']';
                        innerObj = {};
                        innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                        query += param(innerObj) + '&';
                    }
                }
                else if(value !== undefined && value !== null)
                    query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
            }

            return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
        };

        // Override $http service's default transformRequest
        $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function(data) {
            return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? param(data) : data;
        }];
    });

    /**
    *   Create global variable
    *   @return {object}
    */
    app.factory('global', function()
    {
        var global = {
            user: {
                logged: false,
                name: null,
                id: null
            },
            project: null,
            task: null
        };

        return global;
    });
})(angular);
```

index.php

```
<?php 
    // Define application variable
    $app = Yii::app();
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/css/angular-material.min.css';?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/css/flaticon.css';?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic">
</head>
<body ng-app="Organizer" ng-controller="site as main">
    <div layout="column">
        <md-toolbar>
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <span><?php echo $app->name; ?></span>
                <!-- fill up the space between left and right area -->
                <span flex></span>

                <!-- Menu Button -->
                <md-menu>
                    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Menu" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
                        <md-icon md-menu-origin md-svg-icon="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/icons/menu.svg';?>" alt="Menu"></md-icon>
                    </md-button>
                    <md-menu-content>
                        <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in main.menu" >
                            <md-button>{{item}}</md-button>
                        </md-menu-item>
                    </md-menu-content>
                </md-menu>
                <!-- <md-select ng-model="main.select" placeholder="Menu">
                    <md-option ng-repeat="item in main.menu" ng-value="item">{{item}}</md-option>
                </md-select> -->
                <!-- /.Menu Button -->
            </div>
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-content layout-padding ng-include="main.view">
        </md-content>
    </div>
    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/js/angular.min.js';?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/js/angular-animate.min.js';?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/js/angular-aria.min.js';?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/js/angular-material.min.js';?>"></script>

    <!-- Angular app -->
    <script src="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/js/angular/app.js';?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/js/angular/controllers/siteController.js';?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/js/angular/controllers/loginController.js';?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/js/angular/controllers/projectController.js';?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/js/angular/controllers/taskController.js';?>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i just add it to see if it doesn't break anything, but it does and i have idea what to do when the browser throws me a huge error.

the versions of angular i use are:

Angular.js: 1.3.16
Angular-Material: 0.10.0

Comment: Can you add your index.html ?

Comment: @NelsonPatricioJimenez It is a php file, but sure, it's added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add [angular-route](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route) in your php file. (I'm using bower in my app)

```
<script src="<?php echo $app->request->baseUrl.'/dist/js/angular-route.js';?>"></script>
```

If you have not downloaded this file, I recommend you download from the [main documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute).